# How do you rename the child XML elements used in an XML Serialized List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm serializing to XML my class where one of properties has type List<string>.

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

XML created by serializing this class looks like this:

```
<MyClass>
    ...
    <Properties>
        <string>somethinghere</string>
        <string>somethinghere</string>
    </Properties>
    ...
</MyClass>
```

and now my question. How can I change my class to achieve XML like this:

```
<MyClass>
    ...
    <Properties>
        <Property>somethinghere</Property>
        <Property>somethinghere</Property>
    </Properties>
    ...
</MyClass>
```

after serializing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [XmlArrayItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Property")]
    public List<string> Properties = new List<string>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.Properties.Add("test1");
        program.Properties.Add("test2");
        program.Properties.Add("test3");

        XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Program));
        xser.Serialize(new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create), program);
    }
}
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Program xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Properties>
    <Property>test1</Property>
    <Property>test2</Property>
    <Property>test3</Property>
  </Properties>
</Program>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[XmlElement("Property")]` before the declaration of your Properties member.

Comment: When I used [XmlElement("Property")] before my property XML leafs was genereted under MyClass node (they should be placed under "Properties"). Using [XmlArrayItem("Property")] solved my problem. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a WCF service and still use DataContractSerializer, you can simply define a new List subclass:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="Property")]
public class PropertyList: List<string>
{
    public PropertyList() { }
    public PropertyList(IEnumerable<string> source) : base(source) { }
}
```

Then, in the class you are serializing, just specify the member as:

```
[DataMember]
public PropertyList Properties;
```